# sql - find value from a column to find all other values from another column

Tags: sql, if-statement, case

This is a SQL question, I will try my best to explain.

I have a table like the following below

```
id  name    accounts
1   Jim 7001
1   Jim 7002
1   Jim 7003
2   Ryan    7001
3   Todd    7001
3   Todd    7003
2   Ryan    7002
4   Cam 7001
5   Fran    7001
2   Ryan    7003
1   Jim 7004
```

I am first trying to find all values with accounts column of '7001' to find the correct id's. After that I need to only pull the lines with those id's so I can see all the accounts for those specific ids.

example code I am using

```
select 
s.id,
s.name,
s.account

from 
students s

where
s.account in ('7001','7002','7003','7004')
```

---

I can do this with 2 queries one to find id's with '7001' account value and then run another query just for id's but would like to know if there is a way to write in order to have it all calculate in one shot.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tableName
WHERE   ID IN 
        (
            SELECT ID 
            FROM   tableName
            WHERE  accounts = 7001
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac201/3)

The `JOIN` version (*recommended*)

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    students a
        INNER JOIN students b
          ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE   b.accounts = 7001
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ac201/4)

Comment: Can we use also use group by here?

Comment: @AshReva do you want to aggregate some fields?

Comment: @AshReva clarify please what exactly do you need

Comment: No i just thought if we could also use group by. Thats fine. Sorry for bothering

Comment: @AshReva There is no problem for asking `:D`. `GROUP BY` clause can is used when you want to aggregate some fileds using aggregate functions like `SUM(), MAX(), MIN(), etc...`

Answer (score 0):

```
select t2.*
from tbl t1, tbl t2
where t1.accounts = '7001'
and t1.id = t2.id
```

Comment: in case `accounts` is an integer remove quotes

Answer (score 0):

This solution is optimized:

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName as a
INNER JOIN tableName as b
    ON a.id = b.id
    AND b.accounts = 7001
```